# How to use CarouselView in Visual Studio 2019 4.4+ and Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel, visual-studio-2019

I updated my Xamarin.Forms version from 3.4.0.1 to the latest build: 4.4.0.991477, but the CarouselView I was using before, Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView does not work anymore and I get this error:

```
The type 'CarouselView' exists in both 'Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView, 
Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and
'Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

I've looked all over for a solution and replacement for Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView but the best I've seen is Alex Rainman's plugin, CarouselView.FormsPlugin, https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView, but I've read people complaining about some bugs in that plugin.

I've also heard that Xamarin Forms has its own new plugin now? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/ 
But it's very new and there's no one talking about it, not much documentation at all...

So.. for current Xamarin.Forms developers (4.4+), what are you using right now to implement CarouselViews? Is CarouselView.FormsPlugin trustworthy? (I have to update the old CarouselView for a big company so I need to make sure it's good before I push the updated version).

Edit: After uninstalling the plugin:
I'm getting a Failed to resolve assmebly: 'Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' error now.

I'm guessing it's because I have the line

`xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"` in my xaml file, but if I take it out, then my code using CarouselView

```
<cv:CarouselView 
  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding ReadingList}" 
                   Position="{Binding Position}">
    <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
...
```

gets squiggled out

Edit 2: I figured that I needed to change cv:____ to something else because it obviously isn't using the same plugin anymore, so I tried removing the cv: from both and it worked.. is that right?

Comment: XF 4.x has a built in CarouselView.  You should remove any Carousel plugins or packages that you have installed to prevent the duplicate reference.

Comment: Oh so is the code already correct, it's just confused on which CarouselView to use? If I uninstall the Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView NuGet plugin, should I be okay? @Jason

Comment: I cannot say for sure, but that's your error message indicates.

Comment: I'll try it out, thanks!

Comment: @Jason Can you check my edit? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I figured that I needed to change cv:____ to something else because it
>   obviously isn't using the same plugin anymore, so I tried removing the
>   cv: from both and it worked.. is that right?

Yes, what you did is right.

In Xamarin.forms 4.4.0.991477, [CarouselView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.carouselview?view=xamarin-forms)  is a class in `Namespace: Xamarin.Forms` and `Assembly:Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll`.

So you can modify your `cv___` to :

```
xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
```

And use it like:

```
<cv:CarouselView/>
```

Generally, it is unnecessary to use `cv` because [the default namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/namespaces#overview) has specified that elements defined within the XAML file with no prefix refer to `Xamarin.Forms` classes:

```
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
```

So, after you remove the `cv:` from both and your project worked.

Comment: Oh ok thanks! Now for the xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=**Xamarin.Forms.Core**" line you metioned, I didn't actually have that line in my code, is that necessary? 

Before, I just had the xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=**Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView**" reference at the top of my file, are you saying I can get rid of that now? 

Or to just swap the Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView to Xamarin.Forms.Core?

Comment: @chung Yes, you can get rid of that now. The reason is I wrote in the answer that  the default namespace has specified that elements defined within the XAML file with no prefix refer to Xamarin.Forms classes. You are now using CarouselView under namespace. If my answer helps you, you can mark it as the right answer which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: @nevermore I got crashed by `Xamarins.Forms.CarouselView System.IO.FoleNotFOundException.` What file I am missing? The assembly is correct. Thank you